# Misunderstood of doctrine query builder

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I was misunderstood of doctrine query builder getting unexpectable results.

Fist time i use it to get id's:

From class BannerRepository:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('e')->select('b.id as bid')->from('AppBundle\Entity\Banner', 'b')->getQuery()->execute();
```

I'm get sixteen duplicated records, when in database there is only four.
Ok, i'm added `->select('distinct(b.id) as bid')` and that solves problem.

But second time i'm used where clause to filter records by boolean.

```
$shownLast = $this->createQueryBuilder('e')->from('AppBundle\Entity\Banner', 'b')
->where('b.shownLast = 1')->getQuery()->getResult();
```

And getting all the records whatever it accept condition or not.

Please help, maybe i'm somewhere wrong with doctrine usage.

Answer (score 0):

In the BannerRepository you don't have to use the from function, because it's already the repository for the Banner Entity. The first parameter for the createQueryBuilder function is the alias for the Banner. Use something like this:

```
$shownLast = $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
->select('b')->where('b.shownLast = 1')
->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of a DQL query with select, conditions, and order by:

```
$variable=$request->get('variable');
$query = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT b.id FROM App\Entity\Banner b 
                  WHERE b.showLast = TRUE                        
                  AND                      
                  b.someField = :dinamicVariable                      
                  ORDER BY u.name ASC'
    )->setParameters([
        'dinamicVariable' => '%' . $variable. '%',            
    ]);
```